# Different ways to install windows phone application on device

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment, windows-phone-8, installation, xap

I have developed a windows phone 8 application. I have a developer account and unlocked device. Now I'm able to deploy/install the application in my phone through windows phone development sdk.

**Now I want to install this application in another device ( a device of my friend, who is in different location). I don't want to put this application in the app store. I want to mail the XAP file only to him. So is there any other way to install this (XAP file) application in his mobile.**

I am looking forward your responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Are you aware of the Windows Phone's Beta testing. You can push your app to the store in BETA test mode and can specify the testers Microsoft emails ids, so that only those people can install and test the app. The app won't be publicly accessible. and AFAIK, you cannot install unsigned XAP's in un-unlocked devices.

For more details check this : [Beta testing your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Chandra, thanks for your reply. I'm new to windows phone development. Could you please tell me how to sign my windows phone application in visual studio 2012 for windows phone.

Comment: Signing is done by Windows store during submission. I meant to say, to install a XAP in a phone, either the XAP should be signed (which you can't do yourself) or device should be unlocked. Hence the better suggestion is to use Beta testing policy

Comment: This means that our code should be signed before to deploy/install on any device.If this is the case how i'm able to install the app in my device without any signing of the code.

Comment: You misunderstood my above comment. When deploying to an unlocked device, VS does that.

Comment: If I send the generated XAP file to my friend and if he has an unlocked device, will he able to install that xap on his device? If yes, could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: He will have to use the Windows phone App deployment tool ( which comes as part of WP SDK). btw, why are you reluctant to use WP beta test program ?

Comment: My developer a/c has not yet activated, once activated i'll deploy it in the store. And one more question if you don't mind. I have created the application for windows phone 8.0. If  i want to support this for windows phone 7.5 how should I ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42234/discussion-between-nkchandra-and-user2636874)

Comment: ... and wait 2 hours before you can download the submitted app? Not very effective for a development environment, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer this link,

I think this will solved your query.

Using this you can install a .xap file in windows phone easily.

> [How to install XAP on Windows Phone](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2400451)

I hope you will get the answer.

Comment: This is one possible solution, but this again needs the device developer unlocked. We cannot unlock a remote device without disclosing our developer credentials.