# How To install .XAP file in Nokia Lumia 930

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I develop the windows phone App. i want to give the .XAP file to run on their phone. but when send to it through email. he download and want to instal but its become error. give me some solution how to transfar one .XAP file to another mobile and install it.

Comment: A similar question recently asked by someone .. Have a look [Installing XAP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281973/different-ways-to-install-windows-phone-application-on-device)

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order for him to install .xap files that aren't from the Windows Phone Store, he would have to developer unlock his phone. Developer unlocking a phone requires a Windows Phone Store account subscription. If you have a subscription and the WP SDK, you can open up a program on your computer called `Windows Phone Developer Registration` and follow the directions there.

Comment: at this time i dont have the windows phone store account. so thats i can do on thats time ?

Comment: You can either wait until you can obtain your Windows Phone Store subscription and officially unlock your devices to deploy, or you can try flashing an older WP7 phone to deploy .xap files without an account.

Comment: can you tell me who to offcially unlock the nokia lumia 920 ?

Comment: Since the Lumia 920 is a WP8 device, the only way to unlock it is by officially unlocking it. I've outlined how to officially unlock on my original post, and since you don't have a WP Store subscription, you won't be able to do it. Sorry about that...